# Do binary trees have to have numeric nodes? Can a binary tree have a node with a string value?

Tags: binary-tree, nodes

Somebody told me that binary trees have to have numeric values but I have a feeling that's incorrect. I am pretty sure binary trees can have all sorts of values in their nodes. So does a binary tree *have* to look like this?:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
```

or can they look like this?:

```
 "Hello"
   / \
", " "World!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ofcourse. A binary tree class will have a root Node object.

The node class can then decide what data to hold. Whether it be an integer, primitive or an Object. Typical a Node class will have left and right Node pointers, a parent Node pointer, and a data value.

Yes, there are examples of using a binary tree to store a phone book. You would store the Persons name, and number in the Node. Then compare two Nodes by the string name (alphabetically), so we can have a binary tree that looks like your example (with actual names). I hope this makes it clear.